# Microsoft Access: How to sort text column by length of its text string?

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, sorting

I have a column that contains text in my Access database.

Is there a way to sort this column by the length of the strings in it (without having to write lots of code)? Showing longest strings first, for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT StringColumn, len(StringColumn) AS Length
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY len(StringColumn) DESC
```